# How to write text with formatting to a file

Tags: ruby, string

I want to make a file `text.txt` with the content:

```
foo
bar  baz
```

How can I do this correctly?

I tried to write string `x`:

```
x = ""foo\nbar\tbaz"""
```

to `text.txt`, and I seem to get the content:

```
foo\nbar\tbaz
```

Comment: Please correct the number of double quotes in your question. `"foo\nbar\tbaz"` is written to the file exactly as you want, check it in any editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify x as

```
x = "'foo\nbar\tbaz'"
```

Then it will be properly interpret it as a string literal.

Write to file as:

```
n = File.new("abc.txt", "w")
n.write(x)
n.close
```

Output:

```
'foo
bar baz'
```

Comment: Hey, do you have any clue what to do when you get an object like stdout = Open3.cpature2(stuff)?

Comment: what is this Open3.cpature2() ??

Comment: Try it. 'require Open3' and then stdout = Open3.capture2("ls"). I want the output of p stdout in a file.

Comment: You can use convert the result of stdout to string using stdout.join() and then use the same process of writing in file as mentioned in the answer